# Javascript Canvas Rendering Method not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

When I run this code on any other web browser (the latest versions of Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Microsoft Edge, and Opera) besides Internet Explorer 11, the code works fine, but when I run it in IE, the lines that are commented out get "Unable to get property '[Varible trying to be declared]' of undefined or null reference" error. Is there some fix I can apply to this to run in IE. I am also using the most up to date version of IE11.
Here is the code I am referencing:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Page Title
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas>
  </canvas>
  <script>
   var canvas=document.querySelector('canvas');
   canvas.width=window.innerWidth;
   canvas.height=window.innerHeight;
   var createGLProgram=function createGLProgram(gl,shaders)
   {
    var program=gl.createProgram();
    for(var i=0;i<shaders.length;i++)
     gl.attachShader(program,shaders[i]);
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    var linked=gl.getProgramParameter(program,gl.LINK_STATUS);
    return program;
   }
   var myCreateShader=function myCreateShader(gl,shaderScriptText,shaderType)
   {
    var shader=gl.createShader(shaderType);
    gl.shaderSource(shader,shaderScriptText);
    gl.compileShader(shader);
    return shader;
   }
   var gl=canvas.getContext("webgl",{antialias:false});
   //These lines of code produce errors for IE Only
   /*
    var vertexShader=myCreateShader(gl,"attribute vec2 a_position;\n\n\tuniform vec2 u_resolution;\n\n\tvoid main(){\n\t\n\t\tvec2 zeroToOne=a_position/u_resolution;\n\n\t\t\n\t\tvec2 zeroToTwo=zeroToOne*2.0;\n\n\t\t\n\t\tvec2 clipSpace=zeroToTwo-1.0;\n\n\t\t\n gl_PointSize=1.0;\n\t\tgl_Position=vec4(clipSpace*vec2(1,-1),0,1);\n\t}",gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    var fragmentShader=myCreateShader(gl,"precision mediump float;\n\n\tuniform vec4 u_color;\n\n\tvoid main(){\n\tgl_FragColor=u_color;\n\t}",gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
   */
   //Ignore these lines. Don't function b/c lines above aren't defining what is needed here
   /*
    var program=createGLProgram(gl,[vertexShader,fragmentShader]);
    gl.useProgram(program);
   */
   //A continuation of the lines of code produce errors for IE Only, any other ones commented as well
   /*
    var colorLocation=gl.getUniformLocation(program,"u_color");
    var positionLocation=gl.getAttribLocation(program,"a_position");
    var resolutionLocation=gl.getUniformLocation(program,"u_resolution");
    gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    var buffer=gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,buffer);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation,2,gl.FLOAT,false,0,0);
   */
   PixelColor('#FF00FF');
   function PixelColor(HexValue)
   {
    //gl.uniform4f(colorLocation,parseInt(HexValue.slice(1,3),16),parseInt(HexValue.slice(3,5),16),parseInt(HexValue.slice(5,7),16),1);
   }
   function drawOneBlackPixel(gl,x,y)
   {
    //gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array([x+0.5,y+0.5]),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    //gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS,0,1);
   }
   
    //gl.clearColor(1,1,1,1);
    //gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   drawOneBlackPixel(gl,0,0);
   drawOneBlackPixel(gl,1,1);
   drawOneBlackPixel(gl,2,2);
   drawOneBlackPixel(gl,3,3);
   drawOneBlackPixel(gl,4,4);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

In IE11 [WebGL context](https://caniuse.com/#feat=webgl) is accessed from "experimental-webgl" rather than "webgl".

So you have to update the following line:

```
var gl=canvas.getContext("webgl",{antialias:false});
```

Like this:

```
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl",{antialias:false}) ||
         canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
```

Also please consider [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext).

Answer (score 0):

[caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=webgl) states that webgl is accessed through the `experimental-webgl`-context. So you have to use

```
var gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl", { antialias: false });
```

instead